# How to avoid reading letters "NA" as missing (or NA)?

Tags: r, na

I have a large file (csv) of library records that include [Library of Congress classification](https://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/lcco/) call numbers, from which I have extracted the letters. The architecture subclass is NA. So a record classified as "NA 1053 .B69 P4 1994" has "NA" extracted in different column. However, when reading this file into R, these NA letters are read as *NA*, or missing values. Is there any way to avoid this, maybe by designating what should be considered "missing," and how those are coded?

Comment: Is it better to have missing value as `NA` because there are methods to track the missing value for NA `is.na`, `complete.cases`, `na.omit` etc and many functions have `na.rm` as argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what function you are using to read the csv, you can override the default behaviours to interpret `"NA"` as `NA`. Most delimited data reading functions have optional arguments to control what is considered missing.

- With `read.csv`, the [argument](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table) is `na.strings`, defaulting to `"NA"`.
- With `readr::read_csv`, the [argument](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) is `na`, defaulting to `c("", "NA")`.
- With `data.table::fread`, the [argument](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/fread) is also called `na.strings`, defaulting to `"NA"` but also controlled by a package option. More details in the [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md).

So in your example, you would write something like `readr::read_csv(file = "path/to/file", na = "")` so `"NA"` in the file is not interpreted as `NA`. Of course, it usually only makes sense to do this in a situation like yours where `"NA"` has meaning and does not represent a missing value.